# How can I make a submit button placed on an email?

Tags: html, email

I'm trying to figure out how I can make a submit button placed on an email so that when the user opens the email, they see the button, can click the button and then an action is done.

What I need is for the submit click to send info back to my server in some fashion.

Is any of this possible with an HTML email?
Will the action be blocked though due to Security software? or that the email be marked as spam and put straight into a blacklist?

Thanks much.

Comment: Why not just provide a hyperlink instead of a submit button?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HTML email is the way to go if you want to attach an image. Although you can accomplish the same thing with links. HTML forms won't work though. A message formatted with HTML alone will not cause a message to be blocked or marked as spam. It's more likely the source of the message and the text content that will trigger security sniffers to block a message.

Answer (score 0):

Forms are not supported in many mail readers, and are certainly not supported by text-only mail readers.  Consider developing the form as a script on your web server and link to the form from the message.

Answer (score 0):

i never tried to build a form into an html-mail - don't know what happens , but i think thos won't work in every mail-reader (why havn't you simply tried it with one of outlook/mail/thunderbird/... and one or two free mailhoster (gmx/google/web/...) - would take less than ten minutes).

the best way to go definetely is to simply use a hyperlink and so send the data you need via get.